# Apply formatting to tables generated by tablefield module

Tags: theming

I am using the [tablefield](https://drupal.org/project/tablefield) module to allow the user to create a "programme schedule" in a table format. The only issue I'm facing now is that the user would like to be able to apply text formatting like bold or italics to certain fields.

The only thing I can think of is styling through CSS, however, given the dynamic nature of this table, it does not seem very feasible. Is there any other table modules that could provide such functionality?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't installed the module, but from the code it looks like there's an option in the field settings called "Table cell processing" in which you can allow the user to select what Input Format they want. This makes use of Drupal's text formats (Admin > Configuration > Content Authoring > Text formats). You could allow them to use HTML within the cell, or install some alternate Text Format module such as [BBCode](https://drupal.org/project/bbcode).